# After installation Gluu Server(CE) on Ubuntu, My System restarting automatically again & again. Please suggest me what I do to fix this?

Tags: ubuntu, gluu

I follow the following command to install Gluu Server on Ubuntu:

1.Add Gluu Repository
      # echo "deb https://repo.gluu.org/ubuntu/ xenial main" > 
      /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gluu-repo.list
   2.Add Gluu GPG Key
     # curl https://repo.gluu.org/ubuntu/gluu-apt.key | apt-key add -
   3.Update/Clean Repo
     # apt-get update
   4.Install Gluu Server
     # apt-get install gluu-server-3.0.1
   5.Start the Gluu Server and Login
     # service gluu-server-3.0.1 start
     # service gluu-server-3.0.1 login
   6.Run setup.py # cd /install/community-edition-setup
     #./setup.py

Answer (score 0):

I format The System and reinstall step by step as per gluu doc(https://gluu.org/docs/ce/3.0.2/installation-guide/install/). Now it's working.

Thanks!